# Add values of certain keys and append to another key in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an arbitrary number of arrays all with the same format. I am trying to sum the values of keys `[15][17][16][22][18][19][20][21]` and append it to the key `[1]`

**What I currently have**

```
    foreach( $some_array as $mvarray ){

        $mvarray[1]= $mvarray[15]+=$mvarray[16];

    }
```

For testing purposes I am just trying to add key 15 and key 16 to key 1.

**An example of an array**

```
[316] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-08-15 00:00:00
            [3] => RIF0976834
            [9] => 6000
            [10] => 2017-08-15 00:00:00
            [12] => Some Name Here
            [13] => Foo
            [4] => Bar
            [14] => ML350
            [7] => 240
            [8] => YENBR
            [5] => 2.65
            [6] => 1.10
            [11] => RMBCY
            [15] => 141.21
            [17] => 0
            [16] => 6.4
            [22] => 0
            [18] => 0
            [19] => 2.2
            [20] => 0
            [21] => 0
            [1] => 169.45
            [2] => PRY
        )
```

As you can see, the arrays I already have contain a value in `key[1]`. I want to loop through all the arrays and make `key[1]` the sum of `[15][17][16][22][18][19][20][21]`

When I echo out `$mvarray[15]` it echos out with the values for `key[15]`. 
The foreach loop that I am doing does not seem to work.

I did `$test = $mvarray[1]+=$mvarray[15];` which seemed to add `keys[1]` and `[15]` together. So I don't know why my foreach loop does not work.

Any help and pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You're modifying array elements, which won't stick *unless you do so by reference.* See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: You know the index to add and store ! Why you need to use foreach !!!

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` control structure creates copies of the data it iterates on, which means that `$mvarray` isn't an entry of your array, it's a copy. Modifying it has no effect on your array.

In order for your code to do what you intend it to do, you have to access the entry from the original array, you can do so by getting both the key and the value in your foreach :

```
foreach($some_array as $mkarray => $mvarray) {
    $some_array[$mkarray][1] = $some_array[$mkarray][15] += $some_array[$mkarray][16];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You know the keys you want to extract values from and sum.

1. Generate your array of targeted keys (`$keys`).  (I have generated an array with the keys as values, then flipped them to keys.)
2. Use `array_intersect_key()` and `$keys` to filter out any unwanted elements from `$subarray`.
3. Use `array_sum()` to add up all of the values.
4. Add total to value at index `1` of the subarray.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea208153881fa642e544aefcb688e8d147206a23))

```
$keys=array_flip([15,17,16,22,18,19,20,21]);
$array=[316=>[0=>'2017-08-15 00:00:00',3=>'RIF0976834',9=>6000,10=>'2017-08-15 00:00:00',
        12=>'Some Name Here',13=>'Foo',4=>'Bar',14=>'ML350',7=>240,8=>'YENBR',5=>2.65,
        6=>1.10,11=>'RMBCY',15=>141.21,17=>0,16=>6.4,22=>0,18=>0,19=>2.2,20=>0,
        21=>0,1=>169.45,2=>'PRY']];

foreach($array as &$a){ // make $a modifiable by reference
    $a[1]+=array_sum(array_intersect_key($a,$keys));  // filter, sum, add to [1]
}
var_export($array);
// $array[316][1] increased from 169.45 to 319.26
```

Comment: Just to be clear, my answer is looping through all of the subarrays in your multi-dimensional array.  The array in my demo code only has one iteration because there is only the one subarray with a key of `316`.  If you don't want to loop, just use `echo $array[316][1]+array_sum(array_intersect_key($array[316],$keys));`